# Adding 2 drop lists to associated table

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu

I am having an issue trying to add the records using 2 drop lists.
I have a table called Urls which holds the details of url. I have a table called category populates a drop list, I have another table called publishers which populates another drop list.

```
            $query = 'INSERT INTO url_associations (url_id, url_category_id, approved, url_publisher_id) VALUES ';
        foreach ($_POST['types'] as $v){
            $query .= "($uid, $v, 'Y', $k), ";
        }
        $query = substr ($query, 0, -2); // Chop off the last comma and space.

        $result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query.

        if (mysql_affected_rows() == count($_POST['types'])) { // Query ran OK.

            echo '<p><b>Thank you for your submission!</b></p>';
            $_POST = array(); // Reset values.

        } else { // If second query did not run OK.
```

The code above allows me to addd data using the categories drop list but when I try to add the url_publisher_id as 'posters' as $k I keep getting errors in my parsing. If anyone can understand what I am trying to achieve your help would be welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an extra array foreach ($_POST[posters] as $k)

//so it reads

'foreach ($_POST[types] as $v)
foreach ($_POST[posters] as $k) {`

and it has executed perfectly.

Thanks for your help.

Sean

Answer (score 1):

If the value of your $k variable is anything other than an integer or float you'll get an error because it needs quotes around it when you're building the SQL INSERT statement:

```
$query .= "($uid, $v, 'Y', '$k'), ";
```

Note: There are some major security problems in your example. If you put user input from $_POST into your SQL without escaping it you're giving the user the ability to run whatever SQL commands they want to run on your database.

Comment: Thank you but my problem is declaring the variable $k
In the code $_POST['types'] as $v.Decalres the category id 'types' as $v
How do I do the same for the url_publisher_id as a variable 'posters' as $k.
I have tried adding to the line to include the url_publisher_id but without any success.
My error now is that undefined variable k and that then leads to an incorrect integer value.
I am having problems trying to decalare the k variable.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you dellsala for highlighting the security issues I will research this to find a more secure solution.

Comment: I guess i don't understand your question. Can you explain what you mean by "I keep getting errors in my parsing"?

Comment: Hi thank you dellsala for your patience.
Notice: Undefined variable: k 
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'url_publisher_id' at row 1
Query: INSERT INTO url_associations (url_id, url_category_id, approved, url_publisher_id) VALUES (35, 1, 'Y', '')
I understand the need to declare the variable, I have tried extending the line - foreach ($_POST['types'] as $v) - foreach ($_POST['types', 'posters'] as $v, $k) or foreach ($_POST['types'] as $v && ($_POST['posters'] as $k))
And other variations to add both dropdown lists.
Hope this is helps. If not I can email you the complete code.

Comment: Hi delsala, This is what I am trying to achieve but the AND is causing error // Build the query.$query = 'INSERT INTO url_associations (url_id, url_category_id, approved, url_publisher_id) VALUES ';foreach (($_POST['types'] as $v) AND ($_POST['posters'] as $k)){$query .= "($uid, $v, 'Y', '$k'), ";}$query = substr ($query, 0, -2); // Chop off the last comma and space.$result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query.if (mysql_affected_rows() == count($_POST['types']) AND ($_POST['posters'])) { // Query ran OK.echo '<p><b>Thank you for your submission!</b></p>';$_POST = array(); // Reset values.